# css - style div with dir=ltr

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div dir="ltr"></div>
```

That is generated automatically via imap_ function, and therefore I am not able to assign any style to it with the `style=""` tag.

My question is, how can I assign styles to the div above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attribute selector works well if you just want to style this specific element:

```
div[dir="ltr"] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CSS for this?

```
div {
  color: #cecece; /* change the color */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/wxft9/

Comment: I have other divs on the page, therefore I need to style only the specific div above.

Comment: Then try to use a classname! :) @oliverbj

Comment: As said, I cannot add anything to the div, as it's generated automatically.

Comment: Then you can use its property as `div[dir="ltr"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
[dir='ltr'] {
    color: #cecece;
}
```

or with div   -  `div[dir='ltr']`

http://jsfiddle.net/aLvZk/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**:

```
div[dir='ltr']
{
/*Styles*/
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ8TC/)

Comment: `//styles` isn't a valid comment for all browser

Comment: Its not for commenting .I just added it for better understanding of the answer.

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw is it ok now `/* ... */`

Comment: i commented just FYI.